How to convert mutiple level Pandas DataFrame column names into single level?
There are other seemingly similar looking questions which already exist on this site, however all of them appear to be related to performing some form of melt operation, rather than a column renaming operation, which is what I ask about here.
I have a Pandas DataFrame with multiple columns. The column names are tuples meaning that there are (effectively) multiple levels to the column names.
I want to rename these columns, and change the names from tuples to single strings.
I have currently found one way to do this, but I am not convinced this is the best approach.
Since Pandas allows the df.columns object to be replaced with a list of strings of the same length as len(df.columns), one possible approach is to create a list of strings by concatinating the existing tuple values.
Here's some code which does this.
new_column_names = (
    list(
        map(
            '_'.join,
            df.columns,
        )
    )
)

df.columns = new_column_names

Is there any better way to do this? It feels like a lot of manual work to do something which seems like it might be a common operation with a more ideomatic solution.

You can use a listcomp:
df.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df.columns]

